# Finding IP address and port number using socket api?

Tags: c, sockets

I am working on a code where I have need to find the sender's IP address,sender's port no and application layer packet sent by it.

I did it using Raw Sockets (SOCK_RAW), it runs fine and did the job for me but its too much clumsy.

**Question:** I can use SOCK_STREAM and get the application layer packet directly and that's really clean and simple method than using Raw socket but this way I won't be able to find the IP address and port number of the client. Is there any function to which I pass the socket descriptor and it tells me the IP address and port number of the other end. I read a few man pages but I could not find any.

I am using linux socket api in C language.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: What programming language? C?

Comment: oh! I am sorry, I am using C under linux and using the socket api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call [`accept()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/accept.html) to accept an incoming connection, `*address` is a structure that is filled in with the sender's IP address and port number.

Comment: man! now I feel embarrassed...I should have noticed that and use my mind before asking the question. Thanks for the reply!!!

Answer (score 2):

the BSD socket implementation defines a function named [`getpeername()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738533%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which allows to know the ip address and the port of the remote side of a tcp socket.

when you have any SOCK_STREAM connected socket, no matter which side first established the connection, you can call this function to get the informations you need. (this is far easier than a raw socket).

Comment: i know, the link points to the MSDN, but the function should be identical on both systems.

Comment: thanks! that saved me from the donkey work. ( I must now accept that I am really a donkey coz I didn't go through the man pages properly... )